# How do I call my full‐initialization constructor

Tags: java, constructor, arguments

So in my Registration class I have:

```
public class Registration {
    
    private Student student;
    private Course course;
    private String semester;
    
    public Registration(Student st, Course co, String sem)
    {
        student = st;
        course = co;
        semester = sem;
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on how do I call the full initialized constructor (containing the Student object, the Course object, and the string containing the semester) to an object in another class.
(btw all the classes are in the same package)

Comment: What do you mean by "call the constructor to an object in another class"?  Are you just asking how to instantiate the object?  The syntax is just `Registration reg = new Registration(...)`

Answer (score 1):

It might look something like :

```
Registration myRegistrationVariable = new Registration(new Student(), new Course(), "spring semester");
```

or you could create these values ahead of time then supply them to the constructor like this:

```
//initialize student with whatever fields you have for it.
Student student = new Student();
//initialize Course with whatever fields you have for it.
Course course = new Course();
//create a string
String s = "Fall Semester";
Registration r = new Registration(student, course, s);
```

Keep in mind the constructor of any given class is called when you use the `new` keyword.
So `new Registration` as used above will call your constructor with 3 arguments, (because we gave it 3 arguments). Calling the constructor with no args, by using `new Registration()` will call your no arg constructor. If the number or types of arguments don't match one of your constructors, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: No problem! Added a bit more info you might find helpful.

Comment: yeah I wasn't sure how I was supposed to call the Student and Course object in the constructor's arguments, I'll keep this noted now, thanks! ^^.